# Execution time of Service Appointment auto-creation on Work Order creation

Tags: visual-workflow, servicecloud, order-of-execution

I need to create a Work Order (WO) after-insert-triggered flow, but the flow needs to update certain fields on the auto-created Service Appointment (SA) of the WO.
The problem is that I can´t find if the SA will exist when the flow be launched or that can´t be ensured and the SA will be able to exist after flow execution.
Someone can help me?